# Combining Legends in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been having a nightmare sorting a legend problem for a while now where when doing a `geom_point` with a `geom_smooth` I end up with two distinct legends on my plot and try as I might I cannot work out how to combine them into something more usable.

The plot code is...

```
require(ggplot2)
require(scales)
require(cowplot)

palette <- scales::hue_pal()(3)
ggplot(df.Overview, aes(x=datePublished, y=sentiment, colour = type, group=type, linetype = type)) +
                geom_point(aes(shape=factor(type)), size=3.5, position=position_jitter(width=0.3), alpha = 0.5) +
                geom_smooth(fullrange = TRUE, alpha = .25, show_guide = TRUE) +
                scale_x_date(breaks = "1 week", labels=date_format("%b-%d"), limits = c(overviewStartDate,overviewEndDate)) + # limit plot to overview dates
                scale_y_continuous(limits =c(-1,1), oob=squish) +  # set upper and lower bounds of Y axis
                theme_bw() +
                background_grid(major = "xy", minor = "none") +
                labs(x = "", y = "Sentiment Index") +
                scale_colour_manual( values = palette,
                                     name="GSE", 
                                     breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean", "sentiment_body"), 
                                     labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") ) +
                scale_shape_manual( values = c('sentiment_TitleDescMean' = 17, 'sentiment_body'= 15),
                                    name="Story Part ",  
                                    breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean", "sentiment_body"),
                                    labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") ) +
                scale_linetype_discrete(name="GSE", 
                                        breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean",  "sentiment_body"), 
                                        labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") ) +
                theme(legend.key=element_rect(fill='white'), legend.position=c(.05,.75), legend.background = element_rect(fill="white", size=0.5, linetype="solid", colour ="grey30"))    # set legend position
```

Which results in the following plot...
[image]

What I really want...

1. To combine the legends into one (title = "Story Parts")
2. To have the legend key as the correct colour, linetype & symbol as currently they are all over the place.
3. To know if there is a simple method for anchoring the legend position top right rather than having to tweak the `legend.position` parameters each time the plot changes.

Can anyone help out with what I suspect is sorting the `scale_` parts

Comment: You need to give the legend the same name, so use `name="Story Parts"` inside all your calls to `scale`. As to legend position, why not use the default? With your current plot there is no way to place the legend inside the plot without overlapping data.

Comment: THAT was simple and works well thanks Heroka.  Position for legend matters here - it does actually fit top right when the "real" plot is at full scale, just ;o)

Comment: This was [asked and answered](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+[ggplot2]+combine+legend) many times before.

Comment: `theme(legend.position = c(1, 1),
        legend.justification = c(1, 1))`?

Answer (score 2):

Heroka's comment had the answer for the primary question of how to combine the legends neatly.  Super simple... change the call to `scale` so that `name="xxx"` is the same for each one.

Thusly...

```
scale_colour_manual( values = palette,
                                     name="Story Part", 
                                     breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean", "sentiment_body"), 
                                     labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") ) +
                scale_shape_manual( values = c('sentiment_TitleDescMean' = 17, 'sentiment_body'= 15),
                                    name="Story Part",  
                                    breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean", "sentiment_body"),
                                    labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") ) +
                scale_linetype_discrete(name="Story Part", 
                                        breaks=c("sentiment_TitleDescMean",  "sentiment_body"), 
                                        labels = c("x\u0304 (Title & Desc)", "Body") )
```